# Conditional comparison of enum

Tags: objective-c, enums

Is it possible to use enums in a conditional statement, like

```
typedef enum 
{
    kUserCapabilites_0 = 0,
    kUserCapabilites_1 = 1,
    kUserCapabilites_2 = 2
} UserCapabilites;

if (theUsersCapability == kUserCapabilites_2)
```

where theUsersCapability is one of the saved `UserCapabilites`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can compare. You should have tested instead.

Disclaimer: This should hold for Objective-C too. Please check it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum{
   a = 1, b, c
}aa;

int main(){
    aa obj = a;

    if( obj == b )
        printf("Equal");

    else
        printf("Not Equal");

    return 0;
}
```

Result : Not Equal

[Online Result](http://ideone.com/Mt7np)

Comment: like if (theUsersCapability == (TargetScenes)kUserCapabilites_2) ?

Comment: @daidai - Check the example. That should hold true for Objective-C too.

Comment: hmm your example doesnt really help, adding (TargetScenes) and you triggered me to think to put it there, so you get a tick anyway